# how to compare the value of two variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have two variables. var 'a = hello;' var 'b= hello world;'.I want to check whether b(hello world) contains the value of a(hello) or not if it contains then alert yes and value of a  else no and i want to do it in loop.

```
<html>
      <body>
            <script>
                var a="hello world";
                 var b="hello";             
             </script>
       </body>
</html>
```

Comment: javascript and jquery are like synonyms these days.. O_O

Comment: jQuery all the things

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) to check if one string contains other, also set attribute `type` of `script` tag. The indexOf function will return `-1` if the string is not found else it will return the `index` of first occurrence found.

```
<html>
      <body>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                 var a="hello world";
                 var b="hello";             
                 if(a.indexOf(b) != -1)
                      alert("found");
                 else
                      alert("not found");
             </script>
       </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while(a.indexOf(b) != -1);
return YES;
```

This block the function on the while instruction, while a doesn't contains b.
When a contains b, the function go to next step and return YES.

Comment: This will just loop forever. Nowhere does `a` or `b` get set to another value and it will block the whole page so the values can't be changed from any other function.

Comment: User want a loop. it is up to him to make sure to use different threads or strategies do not block the interface.

Comment: For a new programmer who hasn't heard of substrings yet, I'm not so sure OP is ready for threads just yet... But OP decided to delete the question and replace it with nonsense, so no sense in keeping your downvote there.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, I am not sure I understand what you mean when you say that that you want it in a loop ...

```
if (a == b)
  {
Alert ( "yes" )
  }
```

Comment: This is checking the values are equivalent. OP wants to check if any part of the value of `a` is in the value of `b`.